# What’s phrase that people use to eat as much as you want?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms, metaphors

I love expressions and phrases. But I was wondering and I could recall that when parents have their children eat, there are those who force the food down their throats and those who let them eat as much as they want, and I’m the latter. So what phrase is used a lot to express to someone, eat as much as you want.

“I didn’t know you were coming Phil. I guess since you are here there’s some food in so __________.”

I’m interested to hear what anyone thinks they should say, so give it a shot!

Comment: It's not quite clear - by "as much as you want" do you mean "eat a lot" or "eat some". I feel the example with the kids points at the latter, whereas the sentence with the gap - to the former. If it's the former - Decapitated has some nice options. I'd add "enjoy yourself", "be my guest". If the latter - there's the concept of Baby-led Weaning.

Comment: "Eat as much as you want" suggests to me those restaurants where you pay a fixed price to help yourself from a buffet. But you seem to be opposing it to 'forcing children to eat', and in that context "Eat _only_ as much as you want" makes more sense.

Comment: Pig out!!!!!!!!

Comment: I agree with @JulesCocovin. It's not at all clear that the author of the question is looking for an "all you can eat" expression. I think the sense is to find a phrase for "Eat however much you like." That might, in fact, be the appropriate phrase.

Comment: I can think of no word or phrase I could add to the blank in the example sentence that would have it make any sense. (I find *there's some food* ***in so*** to be bizarre.) I also have no idea what's wrong with the already mentioned *eat as much as you want*.

Comment: "Help yourself"

Answer (score 0):

"Dig in!" This has an informal, "enjoy and sate yourself" feel, while saying "pig out" or "stuff your face" is likely to be heard in few places aside from an '80s frat movie.

Comment: I gave you a +1, as I thought a fair answer was  being treated unfairly; perhaps a citation and source might avoid that type of issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

***Help yourself***.

> used for giving someone permission to do or use something
>
> ‘Do you mind if I use the phone?’ ‘Help yourself.’

[-MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/help-yourself)

'Help yourself' is a common polite expression, and when used in the context of offering food or drink puts no upper or lower limit on the amount to be consumed.